# How to blend CMMI and Scrum?

Tags: process, agile, scrum, cmmi

I work in a shop that is certified at CMMI level 5.  This certification is important because it gives us access to certain customers and contracts.  I'm looking at how to blend Scrum with CMMI.  I've found some info on mixing Scrum with CMMI-3, but quite a bit of it is "hand wavy" and wouldn't hold up to intense scrutiny.  Specifically, the organizational KPAs seem challenging.

What experiences have you had (good and bad) mixing the two processes?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This seems an interesting paper by the SEI folks at Carnegie Mellon (not just about Scrum though):

> CMMI and Agile are compatible. At the project level, CMMI focuses at a high level of abstraction
>   on what projects do, not on what development methodology is used, while Agile methods
>   focus on how projects develop products. Therefore, CMMI and Agile methods can co-exist

[CMMI or Agile: Why not embrace both (PDF)](http://www.sei.cmu.edu/publications/documents/08.reports/08tn003.html)

Comment: As a follow-up to the SEI paper already mentioned here, Scott Ambler published an article on Dr Dobb's named "[Agile CMMI: Complimentary or Oxymoronic?](http://www.ddj.com/architect/212501388)" where he's commenting the SEI paper. HTH.

Answer (score 9):

Here is an [experience report on the results of introducing Scrum into a CMMI Level 5 environment to replace waterfall projects for large defense and healthcare contracts](http://jeffsutherland.com/scrum/Sutherland-ScrumCMMI6pages.pdf) (pdf).

Abstract:

> Projects combining agile methods with
>   CMMI1 are more successful in producing
>   higher quality software that more
>   effectively meets customer needs at a
>   faster pace. Systematic Software
>   Engineering works at CMMI level 5 and
>   uses Lean Software Development as a
>   driver for optimizing software
>   processes. Early pilot projects at
>   Systematic showed productivity on
>   Scrum teams almost twice that of
>   traditional teams. Other projects
>   demonstrated a story based test driven
>   approach to software development
>   reduced defects found during final
>   test by 40%. We assert that Scrum and
>   CMMI together bring a more powerful
>   combination of adaptability and
>   predictability than either one alone
>   and suggest how other companies can
>   combine them.

HTH,

Comment: I initially chalked this up to the hand wavy pool, but closer investigation showed the first half of the paper really does address the level 4 and 5 KPAs.  Thanks!

Comment: Unfair comparison!  If you replace waterfall with _any_ other system for project management, it wins out. It's like comparing starving for two weeks with only water... vs... liver and cabbage diets.

Answer (score 6):

I just happen to find a blog on this exact topic: [Agile CMMI blog](http://www.agilecmmi.com)

> A starting point for a discussion on marrying Agile methods and CMMI.

It links to several articles

- [Agile CMMI: No Oxymoron](http://www.ddj.com/architect/184415287)
- [Agile Programming and the CMMI: Irreconcilable Differences?](http://www.adtmag.com/article.aspx?id=10638)

It found the whole of interest so I decided to share it here.

Comment: Just to note - the blog hasn't been updated in several months, but it appears a lot (if not all) of the resources linked to in the posts are still available.

Comment: I just updated the link I I gave which is restricted to the posts tagged agile AND CMMI ; but the blog is still alive.

Answer (score 4):

Another recent article providing real life experience on this topic is "[Mature Scrum at Systematic](http://www.methodsandtools.com/archive/archive.php?id=95)", co-writtent by Carsten Ruseng Jakobsen, Jeff Sutherland

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the previously mentioned documents, I found another one: [Agile Methods and CMMI: Compatibility or Conflict?](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.102.2676) The emphasis of this paper is on Extreme Programming (XP) and how its methods can be applied within an organization attempting to remain compliant with the CMMI framework. Although it isn't Scrum, it might be an interesting read.

Comment: That's exactly the level of detail I had been looking for -- it's the necessary level of detail when you're trying to deal with folks indoctrinated with CMMI.  I wish it had been available two years ago.  But definitely worth an upvote.

Answer (score 3):

Another interesting Jeff Sutherland's paper on that subject is "[Scrum and CMMI Level 5: The Magic Potion for Code Warriors](http://jeffsutherland.com/scrum/2006/11/scrum-supports-cmmi-level-5.html)"

Is is said : "Results show that projects combining Agile Methods with CMMI 5 are more successful in producing higher quality software that more effectively meets customer needs at a faster pace."

If you can read french, here's a very good article on that subject : [Synergies entre CMMI et les Méthodes Agiles](http://blog.octo.com/synergies-entre-cmmi-et-les-methodes-agiles/)

Answer (score 1):

See short but detailed comparison at http://www.processgroup.com/pgpostmar09.pdf

Comment: There's quite a bit of useful information here particularly the mapping from CMMI SPs to Scrum practices.  However, it doesn't broach the topic of going through all of CMMI-3 and into levels 4 and 5 so it doesn't answer my original question.  Very valuable and worth the read though.

Answer (score 0):

On EuroStar 2009 conference Gittie Ottosen spoke about how they do agile at their company. What's impressive is that this company [Systematic](http://www.systematic.com) is creating software for air-crafts, military etc. They do it in compliance with CMMI 5, ISO 9001 and AQAP 150&2110. So I guess agile can be applied to systems with high regulations. Maybe try to look up that presentation, and try to get more info from him.